# Neo4j/Cypher - Unwanted Relationship Returned

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm getting unwanted 'STARTS WITH' relationships returned after running the following:

```
//
//Return tuples required for architecture viewpoint
//
MATCH reqd_adt=(vp_parent:Architecture_Viewpoint {name:'MVp-04 Assurance'})-[:`REQUIRES AT LEAST`]->(adt1:TRAK:Architecture_Description_Tuple)
OPTIONAL MATCH n2adt=(adt1)-[:`OR`]->(adt2:TRAK:Architecture_Description_Tuple)
RETURN reqd_adt, n2adt
```

which results in
[image: Result with Unwanted STARTS WITH Relationships]

Why is this/What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not have neo4j on this machine, but I think there is an option on the interface to control that (show all connections or so)... but long time ago so I am not sure

Comment: Yes - thanks. Pity the default isn't 'off'

Answer (score 1):

From the browser settings (gear icon, lower left corner), expand it and scroll to the bottom of the settings and uncheck "Connect result nodes".

The feature is useful to show context, but not so useful when you only want to see specific results (relationships) returned and not all of the relationships that exist between the nodes.